# How are these expressions equivalent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I saw that
$${y^2\over y^2+1} = 1 - \frac1{y^2+1}$$
but I can't see how, wolfram alpha agrees but I'm still not seeing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally,$$\frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{(a+b)-b}{a+b}=\frac{a+b}{a+b}-\frac{b}{a+b} = 1-\frac{b}{a+b}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1 - \frac{1}{y^2+1} = \frac{y^2 + 1}{y^2 + 1} - \frac{1}{y^2+1} = \frac{y^2}{y^2+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

LHS:
$$\begin{align}\frac{y^2} {y^2+1}
&=\frac{y^2+1-1} {y^2+1} \\\\
&= \frac{y^2+1}{y^2 + 1} - \frac{1}{y^2+1} \\\\
&= 1-\frac 1 {y^2+1}\end{align}$$

It is simply rationalizing the right hand side and hence proved.

Comment: please try to format your answers in $\TeX$

Comment: I don't know why someone gave a down vote here, so I will neutralize it.  +1